# How to deserialise a JSON response with escaped strings included? (Feign Client/Jackson)

Tags: json, scala, jackson, feign

I have a JSON response such as this:

```
    "buckets": [
{
    "info1": "on",
    "info2": "{\"version\":\"v1\"}"
},
{
    "info1": "off",
    "info2": "{\"version\":\"v2\"}"
}]
```

This corresponds to this code:

```
case class Response(buckets: Seq[Bucket])

case class Bucket(info1: String, @JsonProperty("info2") info2: Info2)

case class Info2(@JsonProperty("version") version: String)
```

As 'info2' value contains escaped strings, this is cannot be deserialized correctly and I receive the following error :

```
Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Info2] from String value ('{"info2":"version"}'); no single-String constructor/factory method
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the way the JSON response is. What are the next steps from my end? Do I have to use a custom deserisation technique?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to first escape the Strings and then parse the JSON? For example., Apache commons has this method: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(String)

Comment: I should add that this deserialization is happening by Feign HTTP client + Jackson when receiving a JSON response

Comment: Could you tap into the String even before the Feign HTTP Client could parse it? Can you add some HTTP filters?

Comment: Im not sure if Feign has this capability but I will have a look. Thanks